# Threading Barrier Issue

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a situation where I need one thread to wait until another thread provides it with data. I've created this class :[Propery Highlighted,Syntax Highlighted Version](https://gist.github.com/BenjaminHolland/8464010)

```
public class AsyncObjectWait<T1, TriggerType>
{
    private void _timeout(TimeSpan timeout, TaskCompletionSource<TriggerType> tcs)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(timeout);
        lock (tcs)
        {
            if (!tcs.TrySetException(new TimeoutException("Wait Timed Out")))
            {
                int a = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Timed Out");
            }
        }
    }
    public Task<TriggerType> WaitOneAsync(TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<TriggerType> wait = new TaskCompletionSource<TriggerType>();
        lock (_waits)
        {
            _waits.Enqueue(wait);
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                _timeout(timeout, wait);
            });
        }
        return wait.Task;
    }
    public bool TrySetOne(TriggerType trigger, Converter<TriggerType, T1> converter)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<TriggerType> wait;
        bool set = false;
        lock (_waits)
        {
            while ((!set) && (!(_waits.Count == 0))) //while we havent completed a task, and as long as we have some more to check.
            {

                ; //get the next wait.
                lock (_waits.Peek()) //wait for any other threads to stop using the next wait it, then get exclusive access.
                {
                    wait = _waits.Peek();
                    if (EqualityComparer<T1>.Default.Equals(converter(trigger), _value))
                    {
                        set = wait.TrySetResult(trigger); //try and set the result to complete the task. if we cant, try the next task

                        _waits.Dequeue();
                        if (!set)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

---

To do this, as well as provide a Task-based interface that doesn't freeze my UI while it's waiting.
It seems to have an issue, though. When the Recieve() method is called, it can take up to a second for the task generated by WaitFor to recieve the completion info. I haven't been able to find a reason for this.

Could this be due to async method overhead? Is there another, less complicated way to do this?

Comment: Please edit your question with *small* sample that shows what you asking.

Comment: You probably want to use a callback-style implementation, and do a Interlocked.CompareExchange () to set a flag that your UI checks every so often..

Comment: It takes a second because you have a Thread.Sleep, and I am guessing that you're telling it to sleep one second.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Edited Gist to absolute minimum required for understanding the problem completely.

Comment: @SimonSvensson Actually, the timeout is being set for 10 seconds, not one. During testing, one of the tasks generated by WaitFor occasionally take 11 seconds to time out.

Comment: Please post the minimum code here, on StackOverflow.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Done, although the link remains, because StackOverflow doesn't let me tab or copy preformatted text in, as far as I could tell.

Comment: There is a nice little format button,  `{}`.

Comment: When I highlighted everything and pushed it, it didn't do anything. Not entirely sure why, but thanks for the help. Hopefully it'll work next time I need to post something here.

Comment: @ginkner, are you just trying to add a timeout to a task?

Comment: `lock (_waits.Peek())` looks very very fishy. On the whole this seems over-complicated. _"I need one thread to wait until another thread provides it with data"_ should require a Queue or 1 simple Waithandle.

Comment: I've used an AutoResetEvent in the past, but I think I ran into trouble making it work with the TPL.

Comment: What is `Recieve()`? Unable to understand the problem.

Comment: @usr Recieve is the method that attempts to unlock the thread that called WaitFor. It's a lot like the Set method of a wait handle, except it takes some data to return to the waiting thread.